# S3 Requests Timing out From .Net Core App running in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

Below is my code for getting an object from s3. This code works locally on my machine where I have an aws profile and config file set up. I was under the impression that if I gave my ecs task a role that could access s3 that this would still work without me passing my access key and secret key to the s3Client in my code.

S3 GET Code

```
  public async Task GetFilesFromS3Async(IEnumerable<FileDownloadViewModel> attachments)
        {
            foreach (var attachment in attachments)
            {
                var request = new GetObjectRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = "bucketname",
                    Key = $"{attachment.SubBucket}/{attachment.ObjectId}/{attachment.FileName}"
                };

                using(var s3response = await _client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        await s3response.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                        memoryStream.Position = 0;
                        attachment.FileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
```

s3 client init

```
 private readonly IAmazonS3 _client;

    public S3Service(IAmazonS3 client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
```

startup.cs code

```
services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
```

The role on both my task and ec2 instance have policies that allow for write/read operations to s3.

**EDIT**

The policy I have on my ec2 instance and services running my containers: (Basically all of the get and put ops for s3)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketLogging",
                "s3:PutBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:ListBucketByTags",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:RestoreObject",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:PutMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:PutObjectRetention",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the console of my front end application I also receive a cors error, but don't have cors issues anywhere else on my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timeout sounds like you don't have something set up at the network level. I would expect an exception with a permissions error if it was a policy issue. I would need to know what your ECS task role and attached policies look like, as well as the launch and networking type you are using for the ECS task to troubleshooting advice.

1. Check the roles and polcies

Use the [policy simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) to simulate the GetObject action works for your S3 bucket using the policy you think you are assuming in the ECS task. This will verify it is not the policy or give you more details.

Verify the ECS task role being used and that the role being used has this policy attached to it.  Share what your role and attached policies look like here if you still think it is a policy issue.

2. Verify networking

S3 is typically accessed through the public internet. So, if you aren't allowing ECS public internet access it typically wouldn't work and I'd expect a timeout like you are seeing in your OP.  You need to check the VPC your task is in has public internet access through a NAT gateway or the VPC has a private endpoint to your S3 bucket set up in a private VPC.  You also need to make sure that the Security Group(s) used in your ECS task allow outbound HTTP/HTTPS (TCP port 80/443) traffic to the public internet.

This is more of a networking issue you'd need to get help from over at serverfault.com, but here are some places to get started tracking down a networking issue.

https://serverfault.com/questions/578571/accessing-amazon-s3-from-a-private-vpc-subnet

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-private-connection-no-authentication/

Comment: I ran the policy simulator with my custom s3 policy and all seems well. So I do not think that is the issue. Also I am using ECS/Docker with the awsvpc network type. Is that what you were asking for? I'll add my policy info to the actual question

Comment: After you get this working @ColbyBoren, I'd suggest that you trim down that policy. You shouldn't need all these actions just to read an S3 bucket and this is a security vulnerability.  The policy looks okay otherwise. However, we need to see how you are allowing the client to use this policy. What roles do you have assigned to the ECS task and what policies are attached to those roles? Go to ECS in the AWS Console -> your cluster -> Tasks -> Click on the task GUID in question -> look at Task Role. Does this role have the policy above attached to it?

Comment: If the role looks good (from my previous comment), then the next thing to look at is networking. You generally are accessing S3 through the internet. Need to make sure you have ECS tasks configured to access the public internet or you are accessing S3 privately. I'll update my answer a little to guide you there.

Comment: The task role does have the policy attached.

Comment: Also, it looks like I am getting a CORS error in my console along with the 504 timeout error. My api doesn't throw CORS errors anywhere else except where trying to access S3. So maybe not entirely an S3 error?

Comment: I wouldn't think the CORS errors are related but depends what you are doing. Might add the CORS errors to your question

Comment: You were right! Thanks man. The second link solved the issue.